# Adding a vector to each sublist within a list R

Tags: r

I have two lists with the same structure. I would like to combine them as to produce the following desired output.

```
A <- list(c(1,2,3,2,1,4),c(7,3,1,2,2,1),c(2,3,7,2,2,8))
B <- list(c(2,1,3,2),c(3,1,5,2),c(2,4,5,1))

# Desired Output

[[1]]
    [1] 1 2 3 2 1 4
    [1] 2 1 3 2
[[2]]
    [1] 7 3 1 2 2 1
    [1] 3 1 5 2
[[3]]
    [1] 2 3 7 2 2 8
    [1] 2 4 5 1

# I have tried with the items beloww and nothing works as to produce the shown desired output. Would you happen to know on how to combine the two vectors as to produce the outcome below. 

c
cbind(A,B)
     A         B        
[1,] Numeric,6 Numeric,4
[2,] Numeric,6 Numeric,4
[3,] Numeric,6 Numeric,4

merge
append
```

Comment: You could have `Map(list, A, B)` as the corresponding elements in 'A' and 'B' are of different lengths

Comment: Did not know you could use mapply Map outside of a function and produce the expected output

Comment: Is this is the expected output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the length of the corresponding `list` elements in both 'A' and 'B' are not the same, we could keep this in a `list`.  One convenient function is `Map` to do this on corresponding `list` elements of 'A' and 'B'.

```
lst <- Map(list, A, B)
```

If we want to keep this as a `matrix` with `NA` to pad the unequal length, one option is `stri_list2matrix` from `library(stringi)`.  The output will be a `matrix`, but we need to convert the `character` output back to `numeric`

```
library(stringi)
lst1 <- lapply(lst, stri_list2matrix, byrow=TRUE)
lapply(lst1, function(x) matrix(as.numeric(x),nrow=2))
#[[1]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]    1    2    3    2    1    4
#[2,]    2    1    3    2   NA   NA

#[[2]]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]    7    3    1    2    2    1
#[2,]    3    1    5    2   NA   NA

#[[3]]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]    2    3    7    2    2    8
#[2,]    2    4    5    1   NA   NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Your 'desired output' is not very clear. What is inside the first element of the list? Is it another list?

You can try to use `mapply`, and change the `FUN` to get different output format:

```
mapply(FUN = list, A, B, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

Which gives you a list inside a list.