# R: Flexible passing of sublists to following function

Tags: r, nested-lists

Building upon question [Adding a vector to each sublist within a list R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557131/adding-a-vector-to-each-sublist-within-a-list-r).

## Reproducible example

Taking a slightly modified example here:

I have a list with multiple sublists which store x vectors (here two):

```
listA <- list(list(c(1,2,3,2), c(7,3,1,2)),
              list(c(2,1,3,2), c(2,4,5,1)), 
              list(c(1,4,6,8), c(5,2,4,4)))
```

My desired output is achieved with

`Map(list, listA[[1]], listA[[2]], listA[[3]])`

In words, I want to combine all 'first', 'second', ..., 'inf' vectors of each sublist in a separate sublist to be able to work with that new ordered list afterwards. This works with the `Map()` call shown above.

## Challenge

The problem I'm facing is that `length(listA)` is flexible in my case (within a function). So it could be that I have three lists (as in the example) or 100 or 59, etc.
`Map()` only works as desired if I pass all sublists (here `listA[[1]], listA[[2]], listA[[3]`) in a single call as shown above.

So how can I interactively check how many sublists `listA` contains and pass all of these sublists to the `Map()` call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `do.call`

```
res <- do.call(Map, c(f= list, listA))
resO <- Map(list, listA[[1]], listA[[2]], listA[[3]])
identical(res, resO)
#[1] TRUE
```

Or as @alexis_laz commented with `.mapply`

```
.mapply(list, listA, NULL)
```

---

Or another option is `transpose` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
transpose(listA)
```

Comment: Awesome and so 'easy'! :) Do you know how `do.call()` knows that all sublists of `listA` should be taken in `Map()` and not just `listA` (which is passed)?

Comment: @pat-s `Map` takes input as each corresponding element of the input arguments.  So, when we are passing it inside `do.call`, and specify the function as `list`. It just goes through each list element and takes the individual elements to create the `list`

Comment: An alternative to `do.call(Map, ...)` is `.mapply` (which, in contrast to `Map/mapply`, ignores any names for the output) -- `.mapply(list, listA, NULL)`

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be this:

```
newlist <- list()
for(i in 1:length(listA[[1]])){
   newlist[[i]] <- sapply(listA, "[", i)
}
```