# Adding a vector to each data frame sublisted in a list in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dictionary, apply

I have

```
A <- rep(list(data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,2,1,4),b=c(7,3,1,2,2,1),c=c(2,3,7,2,2,8))),10)
B <- c(2,1,3,2,5,5)
```

and I would like to put `B` as a column of each data.frame in the list `A`

something like

```
[[1]]
  a b c d
1 1 7 2 2
2 2 3 3 1
3 3 1 7 3
4 2 2 2 2
5 1 2 2 5
6 4 1 8 5

[[2]]
  a b c d
1 1 7 2 2
2 2 3 3 1
3 3 1 7 3
4 2 2 2 2
5 1 2 2 5
6 4 1 8 5
```

I have [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557131/adding-a-vector-to-each-sublist-within-a-list-r) some stuff, but I can't figure out how works `Map()` or `mapply()`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Map` like this

```
> Map(cbind, A, d = list(B))
[[1]]
  a b c d
1 1 7 2 2
2 2 3 3 1
3 3 1 7 3
4 2 2 2 2
5 1 2 2 5
6 4 1 8 5

[[2]]
  a b c d
1 1 7 2 2
2 2 3 3 1
3 3 1 7 3
4 2 2 2 2
5 1 2 2 5
6 4 1 8 5

[[3]]
  a b c d
1 1 7 2 2
2 2 3 3 1
3 3 1 7 3
4 2 2 2 2
5 1 2 2 5
6 4 1 8 5

[[4]]
  a b c d
1 1 7 2 2
2 2 3 3 1
3 3 1 7 3
4 2 2 2 2
5 1 2 2 5
6 4 1 8 5

[[5]]
  a b c d
1 1 7 2 2
2 2 3 3 1
3 3 1 7 3
4 2 2 2 2
5 1 2 2 5
6 4 1 8 5

[[6]]
  a b c d
1 1 7 2 2
2 2 3 3 1
3 3 1 7 3
4 2 2 2 2
5 1 2 2 5
6 4 1 8 5

[[7]]
  a b c d
1 1 7 2 2
2 2 3 3 1
3 3 1 7 3
4 2 2 2 2
5 1 2 2 5
6 4 1 8 5

[[8]]
  a b c d
1 1 7 2 2
2 2 3 3 1
3 3 1 7 3
4 2 2 2 2
5 1 2 2 5
6 4 1 8 5

[[9]]
  a b c d
1 1 7 2 2
2 2 3 3 1
3 3 1 7 3
4 2 2 2 2
5 1 2 2 5
6 4 1 8 5

[[10]]
  a b c d
1 1 7 2 2
2 2 3 3 1
3 3 1 7 3
4 2 2 2 2
5 1 2 2 5
6 4 1 8 5
```

Answer (score 4):

The function you want here is `lapply()`. The `lapply()` function performs another function on each element of a list and returns a list.

A possible solution, using the simplified notation, suggested bellow, in a comment, by @BenNorris:

```r
A <- rep(list(data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,2,1,4),b=c(7,3,1,2,2,1),c=c(2,3,7,2,2,8))),10)
B <- c(2,1,3,2,5,5)

lapply(A, cbind, d = B)

#> [[1]]
#>   a b c d
#> 1 1 7 2 2
#> 2 2 3 3 1
#> 3 3 1 7 3
#> 4 2 2 2 2
#> 5 1 2 2 5
#> 6 4 1 8 5
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   a b c d
#> 1 1 7 2 2
#> 2 2 3 3 1
#> 3 3 1 7 3
#> 4 2 2 2 2
#> 5 1 2 2 5
#> 6 4 1 8 5
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>   a b c d
#> 1 1 7 2 2
#> 2 2 3 3 1
#> 3 3 1 7 3
#> 4 2 2 2 2
#> 5 1 2 2 5
#> 6 4 1 8 5
#> 
#> [[4]]
#>   a b c d
#> 1 1 7 2 2
#> 2 2 3 3 1
#> 3 3 1 7 3
#> 4 2 2 2 2
#> 5 1 2 2 5
#> 6 4 1 8 5
#> 
#> [[5]]
#>   a b c d
#> 1 1 7 2 2
#> 2 2 3 3 1
#> 3 3 1 7 3
#> 4 2 2 2 2
#> 5 1 2 2 5
#> 6 4 1 8 5
#> 
#> [[6]]
#>   a b c d
#> 1 1 7 2 2
#> 2 2 3 3 1
#> 3 3 1 7 3
#> 4 2 2 2 2
#> 5 1 2 2 5
#> 6 4 1 8 5
#> 
#> [[7]]
#>   a b c d
#> 1 1 7 2 2
#> 2 2 3 3 1
#> 3 3 1 7 3
#> 4 2 2 2 2
#> 5 1 2 2 5
#> 6 4 1 8 5
#> 
#> [[8]]
#>   a b c d
#> 1 1 7 2 2
#> 2 2 3 3 1
#> 3 3 1 7 3
#> 4 2 2 2 2
#> 5 1 2 2 5
#> 6 4 1 8 5
#> 
#> [[9]]
#>   a b c d
#> 1 1 7 2 2
#> 2 2 3 3 1
#> 3 3 1 7 3
#> 4 2 2 2 2
#> 5 1 2 2 5
#> 6 4 1 8 5
#> 
#> [[10]]
#>   a b c d
#> 1 1 7 2 2
#> 2 2 3 3 1
#> 3 3 1 7 3
#> 4 2 2 2 2
#> 5 1 2 2 5
#> 6 4 1 8 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar option in `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(dplyr)
map(A, mutate, d = B)
```

-output

```
[[1]]
  a b c d
1 1 7 2 2
2 2 3 3 1
3 3 1 7 3
4 2 2 2 2
5 1 2 2 5
6 4 1 8 5

[[2]]
  a b c d
1 1 7 2 2
2 2 3 3 1
3 3 1 7 3
4 2 2 2 2
5 1 2 2 5
6 4 1 8 5
...
```